# DIV over IMG inside TD

Tags: css, image, html

I need to put a DIV over an IMG inside a TD, just to show something, but when I do, the DIV is created under the IMG (not overlaying, just under, like float left and clear right...)

HTML:

```
<table id="table" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/><div>Text over the image</div></td>
        <td><img src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/><div>Text over the image</div></td>
        <td><img src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/><div>Text over the image</div></td>
    </tr>
</table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css like this:

```
#table td, #table td img {
  position:relative
}
#table td img {
  z-index:-1
    max-width:100%;
}
#table td div {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color:#fff;
  width:100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/iyESasiv/1/edit . You can remove background color etc. from css.

Comment: Amazing! I tried it before but I forgot something because my code didn't work.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This will sort you out:

```
#table td { position:relative; }
#table div {
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Just add that to your css for the table

Answer (score 0):

You simply can set the proper index.

```
    <table id="table" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img style="z-index:0;" src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/><div style="z-index:1;">Text over the image</div></td>
        <td><img style="z-index:0;" src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/><div style="z-index:1;">Text over the image</div></td>
        <td><img style="z-index:0;" src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/><div style="z-index:1;">Text over the image</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

of simplier:

```
<table id="table" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img class="imgClass" src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/>
               <div class="divClass">Text over the image</div></td>
        <td><img class="imgClass" src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/><div class="divClass">Text over the image</div></td>
        <td><img class="imgClass" src="something-here.jpg" alt="asd"/><div class="divClass">Text over the image</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and in your css file add:

```
.imgClass{
   z-index:0;
}
.divClass{
   z-index:1;
}
```